# Move/Transfer GameObject to another scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We tryed different ways to move UI-object to another scene, but we failed. Over object is in Canvas.

Method 1: we used LoadLevelAdditive, but there moved all objects from first scene without over Canvas with it's elements.

Method 2: we used DontDestroyOnLoad. We need to change our element on Canvas. DDOL save last position on the scene, but we can't change object at all.

Can you get some advice, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use `Application.LoadLevelXXX`. These are deprecated functions. If you are using old version of Unity, please update it otherwise, you may not be able to use the solution below.

First, load scene with `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync`. Set `allowSceneActivation` to `false` so that the scene won't activate automatically after loading.

The main solution to your problem is the [`SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene.html) function which is used to transfer GameObject from one scene to another. Call that after loading the scene then call [`SceneManager.SetActiveScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.SetActiveScene.html) to activate the scene. Below is an example of that.

```
public GameObject UIRootObject;
private AsyncOperation sceneAsync;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(loadScene(2));
}

IEnumerator loadScene(int index)
{
    AsyncOperation scene = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(index, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    scene.allowSceneActivation = false;
    sceneAsync = scene;

    //Wait until we are done loading the scene
    while (scene.progress < 0.9f)
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading scene " + " [][] Progress: " + scene.progress);
        yield return null;
    }
    OnFinishedLoadingAllScene();
}

void enableScene(int index)
{
    //Activate the Scene
    sceneAsync.allowSceneActivation = true;


    Scene sceneToLoad = SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(index);
    if (sceneToLoad.IsValid())
    {
        Debug.Log("Scene is Valid");
        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(UIRootObject, sceneToLoad);
        SceneManager.SetActiveScene(sceneToLoad);
    }
}

void OnFinishedLoadingAllScene()
{
    Debug.Log("Done Loading Scene");
    enableScene(2);
    Debug.Log("Scene Activated!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Programmer To which gameobject would I attach your script, please?

Comment: @tmighty You just have to attach it to any GameObject that is active in the scene since it's using coroutine, the GameObject must be enabled. An empty  GameObject is fine. After that drag and drop the GameOBject you want to move to another scene to the UIRootObject variable from the script on that GameObject. That GameObject is that dragged to the UIRootObject slot is what would be move to another scene because that's the object I am moving when I did `SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(UIRootObject, sceneToLoad);` in the code.