# How to Transfer GameObject to another scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know this has been asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798666/move-transfer-gameobject-to-another-scene), but it doesn't work. It moves the GameObject to another scene successfully but It does not close the previous scene. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K43wV.png).

Here is the Expanded Screen shot of the project [Expanded Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMBMf.png)

And here is the script but in the script you'll also find a code of a Slide Show menu which will display my models as menu

In function enableScene() On line 1 I have tried to close the previous scene but it doesn't work

```
public class PizzaScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text header;
    public  List<GameObject> createObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    private static int slideIndex = 1;
    private GameObject instance;
    private Vector3 temp = new Vector3(0.34f, 0.074f, 0);
    private AsyncOperation sceneAsync;

    public GameObject Pizza;
    public GameObject Cube;
    public GameObject Sphere;
    public GameObject CocaCola;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        object[] subListObjects = { Pizza, Cube, Sphere, CocaCola };
        foreach(GameObject list in subListObjects )
        {
            GameObject lo = (GameObject)list;
            createObjects.Add(lo);
        }

        showPrefabs(slideIndex);
        StartCoroutine(loadScene(2));
    }

    IEnumerator loadScene(int index)
    {
        AsyncOperation scene = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(index, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
        scene.allowSceneActivation = false;
        sceneAsync = scene;

        //Wait until we are done loading the scene
        while (scene.progress < 0.9f)
        {
            Debug.Log("Loading scene " + " [][] Progress: " + scene.progress);
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Progress Completed.............................");

    }

    public void OnFinishedLoadingAllScene()
    {
        Debug.Log("Done Loading Scene");
        enableScene(2);
        Debug.Log("Scene Activated!");
    }

    private void enableScene(int index)
    {
        SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(1);
        //Activate the Scene
        sceneAsync.allowSceneActivation = true;


        Scene sceneToLoad = SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(index);
        if (sceneToLoad.IsValid())
        {
            Debug.Log("Scene is Valid");
            SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(instance, sceneToLoad);
            SceneManager.SetActiveScene(sceneToLoad);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per fram

    public void OnClickRightArrow()
    {

        plusPrefabs(1);
    }

    public void OnClickLeftArrow()
    {
        plusPrefabs(-1);
    }

    public void plusPrefabs(int n)
    {
        if(n == 1 || n == -1)
        {
            Destroy(instance,0.01f);
        }

        showPrefabs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    public void showPrefabs(int n)
    {

        var x = createObjects.Count;

        if (n > createObjects.Count)
        {
            slideIndex = 1;
        }
        if (n < 1)
        {
            slideIndex = createObjects.Count;
        }

        if (slideIndex == 1)
        {
            header.text = slideIndex.ToString();
            instance = Instantiate(createObjects[0], temp, Quaternion.Euler(-90,0,0));
            instance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(20, 20, 20);
        }
        else if(slideIndex == 2)
        {
            header.text = slideIndex.ToString();
            instance = Instantiate(createObjects[1], temp, transform.rotation);
            instance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 10, 10);
        }
        else if (slideIndex == 3)
        {
            header.text = slideIndex.ToString();
            instance = Instantiate(createObjects[2], temp, transform.rotation);
            instance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 10, 10);
        }
        else if (slideIndex == 4)
        {
            header.text = slideIndex.ToString();
            instance = Instantiate(createObjects[3], temp, Quaternion.Euler(-90,0,0));
            instance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(120, 120, 120);
        }      

    }



}
```

Here is the screen shot [Screen shot of previous scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKJKu.png)

Comment: Does `DontDestroyOnLoad()` not work for you either?

Comment: Op is using dontdestroyonload.... @Imran please expand the DontDestroyOnLoad  AND the ARscene tabs in youre scene explorer and post another screen shot, so we can see what your keeping.

Comment: the problem is that his camera from the last scene isnt getting destroyed. i would suggest closing that scene manually the same place your changing scenes. or making an empty in your new scene to destroy it onload.

Comment: You could make ARCamera a singleton so that multiple ARCameras won't exist

Comment: @Vanethrane I have provided the Screen shot as you have asked. I have also tried closing the scene from the script but it doesn't work.

Comment: put a tag on your AR camera in the scene thats not getting destroyed, and then `Destroy(GameObject.findObjectWithTag("camera tag"));`

Comment: it looks like this will only clear one of your errors though, it says "AR scene not loaded. did you add all scenes to your build in build settings?

Answer (score -1):

It very easy to persist your one game object into antoher scene on loading, just attached thsi script to your desired gameobject.

```
public class DontDestroyOnLoad : MonoBehaviour {

    void Awake () {

        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);

    }

}
```

What [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) work like this:

> Makes the object target not be destroyed automatically when loading a
>   new scene.
>
> When loading a new level all objects in the scene are destroyed, then
>   the objects in the new level are loaded. In order to preserve an
>   object during level loading call DontDestroyOnLoad on it. If the
>   object is a component or game object then its entire transform
>   hierarchy will not be destroyed either.

Comment: OP  is using `DontDestroyOnLoad();`

Comment: My DontDestroyOnLoad will not work because my objects are not in Hierarchy. I am Instantiating them in my script in runtime because I have a menu to display. So now can you please tell me how do I do it

Comment: Man you are instantiate the object that you want to transfer into another scene. Attache this script to your prefab you are instantiating.