# LoadScene Additive makes new scene too bright

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to show an inventory scene if the player presses the I key.

In this inventory scene, the hero object should be shown, and it should be manipulated (for example the current weapon should be changed in this scene), so MoveGameObjectToScene seemed perfect for this.

Therefore I have followed [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798666/move-transfer-gameobject-to-another-scene) and basically did the following which I stated below.

It works fine, but the problem is that the previous scene is still shown. I thought that "Additive" means that the previous scene is not destroyed, but hidden.
But obviously, it isn't even hidden. It really overlaps the previous scene.

Moving it away physically doesn't really help, as the lights from scene 1 are added to scene 2.

I have turned off "Auto Generate Lighting" for both scenes.

[image]

What might be causing this?

Thank you very much for any advice!

```
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject UIRootObject;
private AsyncOperation sceneAsync;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
    {
        StartCoroutine(loadScene(1));
    }
}
IEnumerator loadScene(int index)
{
    AsyncOperation scene = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(index, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    scene.allowSceneActivation = false;
    sceneAsync = scene;

    //Wait until we are done loading the scene
    while (scene.progress < 0.9f)
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading scene " + " [][] Progress: " + scene.progress);
        yield return null;
    }
    OnFinishedLoadingAllScene();
}

void enableScene(int index)
{
    //Activate the Scene
    sceneAsync.allowSceneActivation = true;

    Scene sceneToLoad = SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(index);
    if (sceneToLoad.IsValid())
    {
        Debug.Log("Scene is Valid");
        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(UIRootObject, sceneToLoad);
        SceneManager.SetActiveScene(sceneToLoad);
    }
}

void OnFinishedLoadingAllScene()
{
    Debug.Log("Done Loading Scene");
    enableScene(1);
    Debug.Log("Scene Activated!");
}
```

}

Comment: Seems that there is a second directional light in your inventory scene -> The two lights get added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading an scene "additively" is not what I would use for this (you've already seen the problem, additive means the previous objects are not destroyed when loading the previous scene, but they are not modified in any way, not even hidden).

Instead, you can have several cameras, each with their own "Culling Mask". I'd then have an "Inventory Camera" that only shows the objects from the inventory, and nothing more. The "Main Camera" would have a culling mask that shows everything but the inventory objects.

For defining the culling mask you'll need to define layers. Here some docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html

You can then disable the "Main Camera" and enable the "Inventory Camera" each time the user presses "I". This is done with [Camera.main](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This wouldn't work for me as I have many scenes, and I don't want to re-create the same inventory again and again for each scene. Instead, I will just disable any gameobjects in the other scene, I hope that does the same...?

Comment: In that case you can do a mix of both approaches: have the Inventory scene loaded additively in all your other scenes, and only change the camera when you press "I". Notice the loading "additively" should be done only once, not when "I" is pressed.