# UNITY C# - How can I save a Game Object, that has been instantiated in a runtime, in a runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ive got a Game Object that I instantiate in a runtime. Then, I make some changes to it like: I add some children objects, components etc.
I would like to somehow save this newly created object for me to use in other scenes and sessions.
Question is: how?
Thank you.

PS obviously I cannot use UnityEditor namespace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move/Transfer GameObject to another scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798666/move-transfer-gameobject-to-another-scene)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-use the object in other scenes, you can use `DontDestroyOnLoad` method to prevent it from getting destroyed upon changing scenes. Afterwards, if you goal is to spawn copies of this object, you can disable it and treat it as a prefab and instantiate copies of it when necessary.

If you want to be able to re-use an object after re-launching the game, you might wanna check out ways of saving data in Unity. One simple way would be using `PlayerPrefs` but you would have to write the code for loading/saving the state of your object on your own since it's capable of directly saving only `int`, `float`, `string` data type values.

Here are a couple of references:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

### EDIT:

A more specific solution you can try is serializing a custom class made by you to a `JSON` file. That class would contain the necessary data to re-create whatever `GameObject` you had in the scene.

Creating a prefab outside the editor isn't an option. Here's a reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/a5c02u/save_gameobject_as_prefab_at_runtime/

Comment: That is definitely not enough. The scene object that I want to save is extremely complicated; its got a lot of children, components and stuff. And the thing is that it is built gradually as the user plays the game and then I would like to save it somehow to instantiate it in the next session.

Comment: It's definitely enough to accomplish that. You can try looking at JSON format as an option and check out a concept called Serialization/Deserialization.